# Determining if a subset of values are statistically deviant from the whole

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I have [a set of sports scores](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GQQTXKYQp4LvfGT__3rwLRRVrKwujUnMBaSVmf9kvHM/edit?usp=sharing) in Google Sheets. I have various subsets of scores for which I calculate the averages and standard deviations, e.g. scores by team, scores by slot, scores by the game for the team. I thought I would perform T-tests (which I barely understand) to determine if particular subsets are statistically significant deviations from the overall, but it seems that Google's [T-Test function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055837?hl=en) requires the two ranges to be the same size.

What's the right way to determine if it's statistically interesting that (for example) the first games played by a team have an average score of 12.1, while the second games have an average of 15.6?

[image: screenshot of the Google Sheet linked above, showing that each game has a team name, slot, and game number, with averages and standard deviations for the unique values in each]

Answer (score 3):

##### T-Test Formulation

It looks based off the formulation on the Google t-test calculator that they don't allow you to change sample size, but that doesn't mean you are unable to do so. The standard independent samples t-test formula is as follows:

$$
t = \frac{\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}}{\sqrt{\frac{s^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{s^2_2}{n_2}}}
$$

where $\bar{x}$ is the mean of a given sample (either sample 1 or 2), $s$ is the standard deviation of a given sample, and $n$ is the size of a given sample (i.e. if there are ten scores given, $n=10$). You can see that the formula does not require a restriction of sample size for both samples...they can be different sizes (though that is a topic of its own if sample differences are extreme).

##### Using ANOVA

However, you have several groups that you would be performing t-tests on. This is an issue because 1) you increase the chance of alpha error with the use of each test 2) you make your testing tedious with several comparisons (if you are doing this in a program).

A much more appropriate test in my opinion would be an ANOVA. So in the case of using team color as your group comparison, you would do a one-way ANOVA on all of the eight teams, determine if the group differences are significant, and then perform pairwise comparisons to see which groups were different from each other.

##### Book Recommendations for Both Topics

Since you said you barely understand t-tests, it's likely you may need an introduction to ANOVA too. I can recommend two books in statistics that cover both. The first is Essential Statistics for the Behavioral Sciences by Gravetter et al. It covers the concepts and math in a pretty straightforward fashion. The other book has a more software-driven focus on learning stats: Learning Statistics with Jamovi by Daniel Navarro, which has a really engaging writing style and allows you to quickly apply things in stats software (there is another version of this book called Learning Statistics with R for learning the R language, but that may be comparatively difficult for beginners learning both stats and programming). I really recommend at least familiarizing yourself with these topics first before running these tests, as you can make many errors in testing without a good foundational knowledge of how these work.

Comment: Thank you. Ignoring ANOVA for a moment, what does it mean if the _t_ value is positive or negative? Is the sign discarded via absolute value, before comparing to a value in a t-distribution table?

I've created an updated version of my spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GQQTXKYQp4LvfGT__3rwLRRVrKwujUnMBaSVmf9kvHM/edit#gid=866151803) which I believe is correctly using that formula to calculate _t_ and degrees of freedom.

Comment: Well remember that the t-statistic is based off a subtraction of two means. If the second mean is larger than the first, this will result in a negative t-statistic, as the numerator will be negative and the denominator will be positive, which will consequently reduce to a negative t-statistic. You are correct in assuming that it's absolute value is really the most important part in being flagged for significance. Regardless, I still don't think that using uncorrected t-tests here are useful compared to a full ANOVA.